# Send file with php without POST but in use with type=file

Tags: php, javascript, file, post, ftp

i got such problem, that I must create file sending system in browser, but for big files (>50M). 
I have `POST_MAX_SIZE set at 32M but`FILE_MAX_SIZE`is 128M`.
So I must put type file button and read FULL path to send it for PHP FTP library.
Have you got any solutions?
(`filetype.value returns only filename, not path`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) defined in HTML5 to read the file in to the Client.  Once you have it send it via Ajax, to your server, where you can have full access to the file since it is on the server.

On the server you can set the max file size accepted, according to this [SO Post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: I'm afraid FileReader doesnt't make me too, because sending file via AJAX uses POST array too, and I have POST reduced to 32 M.
I Cant increase limit in any way, because i haven't got such SSH permissions. 
I must get full path from type=file via JS

Answer (score 0):

you can increase file size in php.ini file "upload_max_filesize = 256" and restart apache server

Comment: No, I cant, because it's just space on rented server :<

Comment: // Define file size limit 
$limit_size=50000;

Comment: I must upload files larger than 50 M and more. So I MUST send it by FTP, but form browser.

Comment: So I need get full path from input button and send it to php ;/

Comment: you are not using file input?

Comment: then client must type full path into TEXT field.
bad solution

Answer (score 0):

`upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are PHP_INI_PERDIR settings - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php. They are changable (http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)-

> Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or **.user.ini** (since PHP 5.3)

Using `.user.ini` file in your root directory of web-hosting (most of the webhosting services allow this). It will work if your server PHP version is >= PHP 5.3. PHP will scan your root directory for the `ini` file and merge it with default settings.

I used it recently and changed default value of `upload_max_filesize` from 2M to 5M for my personla needs. It might work for you as well. Create a file named as `.user.ini` and set your parameters as:

```
post_max_size = ...
upload_max_filesize = ...
```

Bear in mind that post_max_size should be greater than upload_max_filesize because the former is upper bound of POST.